# I need to make special formula to sum only specific cells containing the row with text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have more than 1000 columns and rows. I need to calculate the total numbers only from specific names  (in this case the total of numbers which are highlighted on the pictures  )
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple way to do this. Try `FILTER()` then `SUM()` formula.

For Alice `=SUM(FILTER(C2:E5,A2:A5="Alice"))`

For alice+Bob `=SUM(FILTER(C2:E5,A2:A5="Alice"))+SUM(FILTER(C2:E5,A2:A5="Bob"))`

For bob `=SUM(FILTER(C2:E5,A2:A5="Bob"))`

Another way is to use `SUMPRODUCT()` like

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:E5)*(A2:A5="Alice"))
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:E5)*((A2:A5="Alice")+(A2:A5="Bob")))
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:E5)*(A2:A5="Bob"))
```

[image]

Comment: @IlgarSafarli If you found this working please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it).

Answer (score 1):

In case you have many criteria or the number of criteria varies, you may consider to use `QUERY`

Assuming the criteria are on `B1002:1002` (i.e. B1002: Alice, C1002: Bob, D1002: Ted) and the table is `A1:AA1000`

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(QUERY({A1:AA1000},"select sum(Col"&TEXTJOIN(")+sum(Col",TRUE,IF(B1:1="",,COLUMN(B1:1)))&") where Col1='"&TEXTJOIN("' or Col1='",TRUE,B1002:1002)&"' group by Col1",1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

something more advanced.... you can use this formula in all of your 3 cases:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C$2:E$5*1, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A$2:A$5), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(SPLIT(A8, " ")), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(A$2:A$5))))))))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZeOGerAk0dU8DVAHYlByd8lM_jfmlJdHnaoLJuliTw/edit#gid=1480092924)